# How to solve auto logout problem in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-authentication, laravel-session

I have two projects running in the same shared hosting (Namecheap Reseller hosting), have SSH access. Laravel version is 5.4. In both projects, using `database` driver for `session` and `cache`. I have changed the **cookie** name for both projects. But I am facing two serious problems.

1. It automatically logged out authenticated users after a few minutes.
2. There is a blog part of it. If an authenticated user posts something, it showing another authenticated user posted it.

> session.php (thefinancialexpress.com.bd)

```
<?php

return [

    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),

    'lifetime' => 120,

    'expire_on_close' => false,

    'encrypt' => false,

    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),

    'connection' => null,

    'table' => 'sessions',

    'store' => null,

    'lottery' => [2, 100],

    'cookie' => 'fe_online',

    'path' => '/',

    'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),

    'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),

    'http_only' => true,
];
```

> .env (thefinancialexpress.com.bd)

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=database
SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=true
SESSION_DRIVER=database
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
```

> session.php (today.thefinancialexpress.com.bd)

```
<?php

return [

    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),

    'lifetime' => 120,

    'expire_on_close' => false,

    'encrypt' => false,

    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),

    'connection' => null,

    'table' => 'sessions',

    'store' => null,

    'lottery' => [2, 100],

    'cookie' => 'laravel_session',

    'path' => '/',

    'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),

    'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),

    'http_only' => true,

];
```

> .env (today.thefinancialexpress.com.bd)

```
CACHE_DRIVER=database
SESSION_DRIVER=database
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
```

> Please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Are the two projects on the same domain name?

Comment: @xyz no, one is the main domain, another is a subdomain.

Comment: Can you share your session configuration?

Comment: @EliyasHossain Please inspect the session cookie in your browser to verify that they are on each their domain. If the one for the main domain looks like this ".maindomain.com" it will also work for the subdomain, which you don't want. Probably both have that value.

Comment: In that case you can change it with the config variable session.php -> domain

Comment: @apokryfos edited with session file.

Comment: @xyz please check cookie for main domain: https://imgur.com/BfugKJA And for subdomain: https://imgur.com/DnZe93y

Comment: @EliyasHossain You can read more about shared cookies between main and subdomains here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23086139/1732359

Answer (score 1):

In your config/session.php you can increase the lifetime, Eliya in your .env file set SESSION_LIFETIME to a higher number as per your requirement.

```
'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120), //120 minutes

'expire_on_close' => false,
```